# I can't change version of PHP

Tags: php, 500-internal-error

I recently upgraded the PHP version on my website from 7.4 to 8.0, but now I'm encountering an error 500.

To troubleshoot the issue, I performed the following steps:

Disabled all plugins: I deactivated all the plugins installed on my website to check if any of them were causing the error.

Switched to the Twenty Twenty-Three theme: I changed my current theme to the default Twenty Twenty-Three theme to rule out any theme-related conflicts.

Despite these efforts, I'm still facing the same error. I have confirmed that the issue is not related to memory constraints, as my PHP configuration allows for 1024M of memory.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this error.

Thank you

Comment: you should check your PHP error log, in the meantime you should downgrade to 7.4 until you know the cause of the problem. Your host can help you downgrade, but until you've checked the PHP error log there's not a lot that can be done to help you

Comment: the PHP error log says this: 

Warning: 
Use of undefined constant ‘WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE’ - assumed '‘WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/site/public_html/wp-config.php on line 6

Comment: Any other entries in the error log? A PHP warning wouldn't throw a 500 error.

Comment: Is your WP version up-to-date? That's the only thing I can think of that might impact that.